# ModuleNotFoundError in Python3

Tags: python, ubuntu, module

I am trying to run a program in python in ubuntu, I have this structure

```
├── package1
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── _init_.py
│   │   └── meow.py
│   └── _init_.py
├── package2
│   └── trials
│       ├── herekitty.py
│       └── _init_.py
```

I am importing meow to herekitty like this

```
from package1.components import meow

meow.meow()
```

but I keep getting this error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package1'`

I have tried solutions online but nothing worked, please help.

Comment: Hi, Afaf! Can you show us the command used to run your code? Do you run on the root folder?

Comment: I've got the answer thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is your `_init_.py` file. It should be `__init__.py` with double underscores.
The second issue is you are trying to import packages, so you have to first install these packages locally and then call them.

In your project directory, create a setup.py script with the following content:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='package1',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

Then, open a terminal and navigate to the root directory of your project (where setup.py is located). Use the following command to install the package locally:

```
pip install .
```

The dot `.` after pip install tells pip to install the package from the current directory. After all these steps, you should be able to import modules from your packages within your project.